# Which android control should i use to get 2 by 2 scrollable grid in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, tablelayout, grid-layout

How can i have 2 by 2 scrollable Grid? Which control should i use?

I tried Grid-View and as Grid-View can not have fixed rows so should i use Table-Layout or Grid-Layout ?  or use linear-Layout in Grid-View ?

I want image to be displayed without being scaled down or scaled up so i am using AUTO_FIT and i get three rows with the below code but i want only two rows and two columns

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ImageView view;

    if (convertView == null) 
    {

        view = (ImageView) convertView;
        view = new ImageView(context);
        view.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT, GridView. AUTO_FIT));

    }
    else
         view = (ImageView) convertView;

    String url = getItem(position);

    Picasso.with(context).load(url).error(R.mipmap.no_photo).fit().into(view);

    return view;
}
```

Below is the sample attached image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`. This will allow you to specify the number of columns:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));
```

If you would like to set the row height so that two rows always match the height of your screen, you could set it inside `onBindView()` of your adapter. You can ascertain the relative row height by subtracting the screen height from the height of your `Toolbar`:

```
//Could calculate this in your `Activity` class and pass the value to your Adapter
public int getProprtionalRowHeight() {

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

    return ((height - toolbar.getHeight()) / 2);

}
```

In your adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //...

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = valueReturnedFromGetProprtionalRowHeight;
        holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [StaggeredGrid](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) for this purpose its stable and easy to use.
you can also use [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) with recycler view.

Comment: Just a regular `GridLayoutManager` with a `RecyclerView` should work fine as well.

Comment: alternative is StaggeredGridLayoutManager with recycler view.

Comment: http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/